# Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.commons.dbcp2.LocalStrings

Tags: java, database, bundle

I just wanted to connect to an SQL database, and this error occurred. Actually, I didn't even know what a Bundle was, and after researching the subject, I don't actually want to do a translation or anything like that, so I don't understand why I have this error.

```
 java.util.MissingResourceException: can't find bundle for base name org.apache.commons.dbcp2.LocalStrings, locale en_US
```

Here the code:

```
    import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

    ...

    private BasicDataSource connectionPool;

    private void initConnection(){
    connectionPool = new BasicDataSource(); // My error points to this line
    connectionPool.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connectionPool.setUsername("username");
    connectionPool.setPassword("password");
    connectionPool.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://IP:Port/db?autoReconnect=true");
    connectionPool.setInitialSize(1);
    connectionPool.setMaxTotal(10);
    mysql = new MySQL(connectionPool);
    mysql.createTables();
}
```

EDIT:

Using maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In BasicDataSource, the compiler cannot find all required files. That's why the program fails to compile at the line you're trying to create a new BasicDataSource.

1. Clean your projects folder (how to do that depends on your IDE) and rebuild your project.
2. Did you use a dependency manager like Maven, Ant or Gradle to import the Bundle? If so, make sure it is imported correctly.
3. Is the bundle you're using complete & up-to-date? Maybe some files were re-named, or you didn't import them the way they ought to be.